# Unity app calling jar only once on the first android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, jar, logcat

Looking at my debug message in `Terminal` using `$ adb logcat -s "app"` and `$ adb logcat -s Unity`, I have noticed that my `JAR` file is only consulted **once** when I **first** build my app to `Android` (`.APK`) but every time afterward that I just `run` my app, the plug-in `JAR` file is not consulted. Why is that?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        Log.i("app", "MyMethod entered");

        if (blah)
        {
            Log.d("app", "If entered");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("app", "Else entered");
        }

        blah
    }
}
```

Using `$ adb logcat -s "app"` I see `Log.i` and `Log.d` messages, and below in my `Unity3D` code, I see the `Debug.Log` message using `$ adb logcat -s Unity`

```
public class MyUnityClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void MyUnityMethod()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        try
        {
            using ( AndroidJavaObject androidJavaObject = new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.unityplugin.MyClass") )
            {
                if (androidJavaObject != null)
                {
                    androidJavaObject.CallStatic("MyMethod");
                    Debug.Log("androidJavaObject != null SUCCESS!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Every time I run my app on the tablet, a script calls `MyUnityMethod()` which in turn calls `MyMethod()` of my `JAR`, but after the first build, I never see those debug messages again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `AndroidJavaClass` instead of `AndroidJavaObject`. Also, don't create and destroy the Object each time. Don't enclose the code with the `using` statement. Just declare the variable as a global variable then re-use it.

**Java**:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        Log.i("app", "MyMethod entered");
    }
}
```

**C#**:

```
AndroidJavaClass customClass;

void Start()
{
    //Replace with your full package name
    customClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.unityplugin.MyClass");

    //Call function
    MyMethod();
}

public void MyMethod()
{
    customClass.CallStatic("MyMethod");
}
```

---

If you need the `MyMethod` function to be static then make the `customClass` variable `static` too:

**C#**:

```
static AndroidJavaClass customClass;

void Start()
{
    //Replace with your full package name
    customClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.unityplugin.MyClass");

    //Call function
    MyMethod();
}

public static void MyMethod()
{
    customClass.CallStatic("MyMethod");
}
```

Comment: "You have to use AndroidJavaClass instead of AndroidJavaObject" - i don't think that's correct. you can call static methods using an AndroidJavaObject instance.

Comment: Yes, `AndroidJavaObject` can be used based on the doc examples but I have personally had problems with it too. Problems went away when I switched to `AndroidJavaClass`. I have since been using `AndroidJavaClass`. That's why I encouraged OP to use what works for me.

Comment: AndroidJavaClass is derived from AndroidJavaObject. Also, it doesn't define any new methods (except for constructors). When you call CallStatic, you're effectively invoking the AndroidJavaObject method. Should make really no different at all.

Comment: Yes, I know about this. The constructor is different and I assume that makes a difference. If OP finds that this doesn't work then I will get ride of it. Although, I expect it to work.